# A simple question about the dimension of subspace.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

I have a simple question:

Let $A$, $B$ be closed subspaces of banach space $X$ and $B\subseteq A$, if $\dim A/B<\infty$ and $\dim B<\infty$, then $\dim A<\infty$? Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens just because they are vector spaces. A set of generators for $A$ can be obtained by adding to a (finite) set of generators of $B$ a (finite) set of representants for the generators of $A/B$.

Comment: :I am sorry. I can not understand. Could you explain more specific?

Comment: The dimension of a vector space (and of a Banach space) is given as the cardinality of a base. The quotient $A/B$ has a vector space structure too, but it is a quotient anyway, the vectors of $A/B$ are equivalence classes of vectors in $A$, where two vectors in $A$ are considered equivalent if their difference is in $B$. To prove your point, you need to find a finite set of generators of $A$, so any element of $A$ can be obtained as a linear combination of these generators. So given a base of B, and a base of A/B (choose vectors in A to represent it), every vector can be written (continues...)

Comment: ... as a sum involving a vector in B and some combination of your "realizations" of your chosen base of $A/B$. The point is that $A/B$ is not any specific "orthogonal subspace" to $B$ in $A$, but any "complement" may serve to represent the quotient. You will get a better picture if you imagine that A is $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $B$ the horizontal plane through the origin. $A/B$ is just the set of planes parallels to $B$, but it can be **represented** using one point for each of those planes, say the $z$ axis.

Comment: @rewitten: Thanks for your detailed answer. I know how to prove this problem.